# Ubuntu 18.04 is too slow on my Asus r558ur

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, nvidia-geforce, grub-legacy

*Ubuntu 18.04* is too slow on my *Asus r558ur* with 8GB RAM, 8GB swap area, 2GB Nvidia GeForce 930mx. All the graphics elements seem to appear in a sliding motion with some lag  and even dragging windows seems to flicker slowly. On booting from Live USB everything works fine though. Installation is done in *Legacy BIOS*.

Output for`lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|DISPLAY'` command:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520]
    Kernel modules: i915
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 930MX] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM108M [GeForce 930MX]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Content of `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: I changed tried switching to nvidia driver from nouveau display driver but then boot gets stuck at gnome display manager starting..

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot in BIOS?

Comment: Also I uninstalled nd reinstalled nvidia components nd switched to the latest one.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Yes secure boot is disabled nd CSM is enabled.

Comment: CSM is not needed, but Secure Boot should be disabled to be able to load the drivers.

Comment: Ok sorry for the delay

Comment: You can leave CSM if you installed that way.

Comment: HI I Hhave edited the question

Comment: OK. Didn't you use something like `nomodeset`? Neither of modules are loaded. Please add output of `/etc/default/grub`.

Comment: yes, i did use **nomodeset** and output have been added. thanks

Comment: So it is not a surprise that drivers don't work.

Comment: thanks aIot ,I am a beginner. can u tell me which wud be the best driver to use nvidia or nouveau??

Comment: Nvidia should be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

You disabled loading any kernel drivers for your graphics.