# Ubuntu 18.04 is very slow on high end laptop

Tags: nvidia

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a laptop and it worked perfectly. After installing it on another one (Asus RoG, i7, Nvidia GTX 950M, 16gb RAM), everything worked so poorly.

How it manifests:  Whenever I want to drag a window with my mouse, or to write something, or to select an area on the screen, the rendering is so slow.

[image: black screen]

EDIT1: After doing what pilot6 pointed out, I managed to go past the slowness, but got stuck in an infinite loop at the login screen. Heynnema tried to help me out, but my .Xauthority file was missing.

EDIT2: In the end I gave up and reinstalled it again, but this time I chose something else instead of 'nomodeset' (noapic, nolapic, acpi=off), after some research. That fixed my problem.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90478/discussion-on-question-by-olddew-ubuntu-18-04-is-very-slow-on-high-end-laptop).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 is too slow on my Asus r558ur](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1122290/ubuntu-18-04-is-too-slow-on-my-asus-r558ur)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your initial problem of video slowness** is caused by your Nvidia drivers needing reinstallation, and the removal of `nomodeset` in your `/etc/default/grub`.

---

**Now, we clear up your login problem.** If you've been starting graphic applications from the terminal using `sudo`, that's what probably caused your problem. Always use `sudo -H`.

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type:

  - `sudo mount -o remount,rw /` # remount the disk as rw
  - `cd /home/your_username` # change directory
  - `ls -al .*thority*` # list some files

You should see something like this...

```
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username 407910 Nov  2 08:56 .ICEauthority
-rw------- 1 your_username your_username     58 Jun 23  2017 .Xauthority
```

If it DOES NOT show `-rw-------` then...

- `sudo chmod 600 .*thority*` # change file protection

If it DOES SHOW `root root` then...

- `sudo chown your_username:your_username .*thority*` # change file ownership
- `reboot` # reboot the computer

Reboot and see if you can log in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but after I write the "ls -al .*thority*" command, I don't see .Xauthority. I only see .ICEauthority. As a result, the other commands do not help me.

Comment: @OldDew is .ICEauthority owned by root:root, or by you? If root:root, then the other commands will still work for you.

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. In the end I gave up and reinstalled it again, but this time I chose something else instead of 'nomodeset' (noapic, nolapic, acpi=off), after some research. That fixed my problem. The install went smoothly and I never had those problems again. The problem would have been fixed by this answer if I had the .Xauthority file.

Comment: @OldDew but... by setting **noapic, nolapic, acpi=off**, you've partially crippled your computer.

Comment: That was the only way I could work around it. After installing it, I've changed them back to normal and now everything seems fine.